# Is it possible to do ssh FROM ovh shared-hosting?

Tags: ssh, ovh

I need to launch a script on a Raspberry Pi from my OVH web site.

The Raspberry Pi is behind a modem and I redirected port 22 to the Raspberry Pi local address. If I try to connect with the modem public IP (eg 91.XX.YY.ZZ) from a computer on the LAN it works as expected : `ssh pi@91.XX.YY.ZZ` works.

However if I try to do the same command from the OVH shared server (I ssh from my computer to OVH server, and when connected type the command above), I get `ssh: connect to host 91.XX.YY.ZZ port 22: Connection refused` although I set up temporarily the Raspberry Pi to allow `PasswordAuthentication yes` (and rebooted it). I would expect to be prompted for password when ssh-ing from the OVH host.

So now I fear ssh request emitted from OVH server may be blocked by OVH (as `ping` is for example), but would it give such `connection refused` message, and how can I test it ? Otherwise what did I do wrong ?

Any help greatly appreciated!

Answer (score 1):

After a bunch of research with other key words (`php ssh2_connect OVH`) it seems that it is not possible do ssh FROM OVH shared-hosting. [Here is a discussion from 2019 (in French)](http://community.ovh.com/t/la-fonction-php-ssh2-connect-nest-pas-reconnue/14070/4).